# Can I use an internal AWS hostname for my Route 53 Hosted Zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am setting up a private hosted zone, with restrictions to a specific VPC.  I am using a non-alias definition of my two EC2 servers.  I am setting up a failover routing policy to create an active-passive setup.

My applications are all internally facing, I do not have a public domain name to use.  Can I somehow use an internal amazon hostname as the domain name?

Comment: If you don't have a public domain name to use, you could always use the (longer and unfriendlier) Amazon-provided DNS name of an Elastic Load Balancer in front of an Autoscaling Group containing your two EC2 servers.

Comment: We are not running an ELB or any auto-scaling.  Is there another hostname we can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a fictitious domain name on a *private* hosted zone in Route 53.

For example, you could create a hosted zone for the domain name `smoke.internal` and then assign hostnames to your instances like `magic.smoke.internal` and `mirror.smoke.internal`.  Just don't use someone else's real domain name, because you would never be able to access their domain from inside your VPC, and do make your fictitious domain name have at least one dot in it.

Comment: I am glad to hear it, this was something not easy to determine from the AWS documentation!